# How to find an expression for a number via a given set of math operators and constants?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, computer-science

Consider one gives you $n$ digits of a (possibly irrational) number and a finite set of math operators and constants, like $\{\sin(x), \ln(x),+,\times, \pi,e,7\}$. Then he asks you to build a mathematical expression just using these operators and constants which its $n$ first digits are exactly what is given to you. For example:

For the number $6.5892187094970913045\,$with $20$ digits, the expression $7+\sin(e+\pi)$ is a solution because the first $20$ digits of its value are exactly what is given but there might be other solutions too.

> Is there any effective algorithm or software to solve this type of problems at least in very simple cases? If yes, please introduce your references. When is there a *unique* expression for a given number up to a fixed set of operators and constants? What sort of necessary and sufficient conditions are necessary for proving such a uniqueness?

Comment: The [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) might be of interest to you; you put in a number, and it spits out a guess as to what it might be.

Comment: @Meelo Thanks for your interesting and useful guidance.

Comment: You could also check out RIES http://mrob.com/pub/ries/ries.php?target=6.58921870&rst=, it finds your number as $7-\sin(e)$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for very simple cases brute force might work, since "simple" implies a complexity bound. 
Convert your set of constants and operators to a context-free grammar, generate terms, and evaluate the terms to see if they satisfy your equality condition; quit when you hit the complexity bound. A reference:

[Generating all words in a language from CFG](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36403/generating-all-words-in-a-language-from-cfg)

Showing uniqueness is going to be tougher. Here's a somewhat artificial example for you. Imagine a theory which contains no axioms asserting the equality of any two terms. Now think of the Herbrand Universe: no two terms can be equal, so once the algorithm finds a solution, it's guaranteed to be unique. I can't think of a proof right now, but I suspect the uniqueness condition is going to be closely tied to the particulars of the theory under consideration.